# POSIX way to add two numbers together without external program?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'd like to POSIX-ly add two numbers together in my shell script.  I know I can do this:

```
a=1
b=2
sum=$((a+b))
```

But if I try that with `` ` `` (i.e. `` sum=`(a+b)` ``), it doesn't work; and the `$( ... )` syntax isn't POSIX.  I can also pipe it to `bc` or `expr`, but I'd prefer not to, if I can help it.

Comment: It's already POSIX syntax, `$((...))` is arithmetic expansion, not command substitution `$(...)`.

Comment: This is a misleading question.  `$((...))` is POSIX.  So is `$(...)`.  There is no problem here at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the false assumption that `$((...))` is not POSIX compliant, which it is.

Comment: What _exact_ shell are you using?  You don't happen to be on Solaris using `/bin/sh` by any chance?  That particular shell (which is linked to `/bin/jsh`) is _not_ fully POSIX-compliant.  Try using `/bin/ksh` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The `$((...))` syntax **is** POSIX. **[Link here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)**.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the syntax for a ["command substitution" `$(…)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) with a couple of parenthesis inside (which also have specific syntax meanning): `$( (…) )` with an Arithmetic expansion `$((…))` (note the lack of spaces).

The `$((…))` is indeed [specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) .

Comment: `$(...)` is *also* POSIX.

Comment: @Wildcard I never said it didn't. If you look at the link given in the answer, it happens to be from the POSIX spec already.